# Throw 404 error when uri is not registered in the router class

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I' am trying this from yesterday but can't find any resources to help me out. I' am building my own custom MVC for learning purpose. I' am stuck at a point where when a uri is not registered in the router class, it should throw in a 404 error message. I have tried a lot of tricks but nothing worked for me.

***router.php***

```
$router->get('', 'homeController@index', 'home');
$router->get('contact', 'contactController@index', 'contact');
$router->get('contact/locations', 'contactController@locations', 'contact');
```

***controller.class.php***

```
class Controller{
    public function controller($ContollerMethod = null){
        $contoller = explode('@', $ContollerMethod);
        if( !empty($contoller[0]) ){
            return $contoller[0];
        }
    }

    public function method($ContollerMethod = null){
        $method = explode('@', $ContollerMethod);
        if( !empty($method[1]) ){
            return $method[1];
        }
    }

    public function view($view = null){
        if( empty($view) ){
            $view = 'page';
        }
        $file = site_path() . '/app/views/' . $view . '.php';
        require_once($file);
    }

    public function render($ContollerMethod = null, $view = null, $data = array() ){
        $controller = $this->controller($ContollerMethod);
        $method = $this->method($ContollerMethod);

        if( file_exists(site_path() . '/app/controllers/' . $controller . '.php') ){
            require_once(site_path() . '/app/controllers/' . $controller . '.php');
            if( !method_exists($controller, $method) ){
                die('No method \'<em>' . $method . '</em>\' exists on Controller \'<em>' . $controller . '</em>\'');
            }

            $params = array();
            call_user_func_array( [$controller, $method], $params );

            $master = site_path() . '/app/views/master.php';
            if( file_exists($master) ){
                require_once( site_path() . '/app/views/master.php');
            }

        } else {
            die('Controller \'<em>' . $controller . '</em>\' doesn\'t exists');
        }
    }

}
```

***router.class.php***

```
class Router extends Controller{

    public function get($uri = null, $ContollerMethod = null, $view = null){
        $permalink = get_permalink();
        if( $permalink == $uri and strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) == 'get' ){
            $this->render($ContollerMethod, $view);
        }
    }

    public function post($uri = null, $ContollerMethod = null, $view = null){
        $permalink = get_permalink();
        if( $permalink == $uri and strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) == 'post' ){
        }
    }

    public function ajax($uri = null, $ContollerMethod = null, $view = null){
        $permalink = get_permalink();
        if( $permalink == $uri and !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest'){
        }
    }

}
$router = new Router;
```

***Example:***

`contact`, `contact/locations` are registed in the `router.class.php` so there is no problem and everything works fine, but the uri `errorexample` is not registered and it should show 404 error message from the views.

Please any help.

Comment: would the [Chain of Responsibility](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/chain_of_responsibility) pattern help with this issue? i.e. pass the request to the chain of handlers if no-one processes it then throw the '404' error?

Answer (score 2):

basic solution (but not the [best](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/chain_of_responsibility)) is add a return value (`boolean`) for `Router::get()`. The value returned is `true` if the `route` was handled and `false` if the route is not handled

**router.php**

```
// route handlers found
$founded = 0;

if( $router->get('', 'homeController@index', 'home') ){
    $founded++;
}
if( $router->get('contact', 'contactController@index', 'contact') ){
    $founded++;
}
if( $router->get('contact/locations', 'contactController@locations', 'contact') ){
    $founded++;
}

// no handlers found... the route is handled by error controller
if( $founded <= 0 ){
     $router->get('404', 'errorController@index', '404');
}
```

**controller.class.php**

```
class Router extends Controller{

    /**
    * Return true if a controller is found for handle the route
    * @return boolean
    */
    public function get($uri = null, $ContollerMethod = null, $view = null){
        $permalink = get_permalink();

        if( $permalink == $uri and strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) == 'get' ){
            return $this->render($ContollerMethod, $view); // return true if a controller and a view are found
       }
       return false; // added this line
    }

    //.............
```

implement same loginc in `controller::render()`

**controller.class.php**

```
class Controller{

    /**
     * Return true if a controller is found
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function render($ContollerMethod = null, $view = null, $data = array() ){
        $controller = $this->controller($ContollerMethod);
        $method = $this->method($ContollerMethod);

        if( file_exists(site_path() . '/app/controllers/' . $controller . '.php') ){
            require_once(site_path() . '/app/controllers/' . $controller . '.php');
            if( !method_exists($controller, $method) ){
                die('No method \'<em>' . $method . '</em>\' exists on Controller \'<em>' . $controller . '</em>\'');
            }

            $params = array();
            call_user_func_array( [$controller, $method], $params );

            $master = site_path() . '/app/views/master.php';
            if( file_exists($master) ){
                require_once( site_path() . '/app/views/master.php');
            }

            return true; // add this line

        } else {
            die('Controller \'<em>' . $controller . '</em>\' doesn\'t exists');
        }
        return false; // add this line
    }

// .....................................
```

**now... my two cents**

in your logic each router was called every time even if a controller is found. One optimization is stop this process if a controller was found, eg.:

**router.php**

```
if( $router->get('', 'homeController@index', 'home') ){
    exit;
}
if( $router->get('contact', 'contactController@index', 'contact') ){
    exit;
}
if( $router->get('contact/locations', 'contactController@locations', 'contact') ){
     exit;
}

// no handlers found... the route is handled by error controller
$router->get('404', 'errorController@index', '404');
```

*Side note: this a "spaghetti code" solution* and sorry for my very bad english :(